# Adding data to Google spreadsheet while creating using PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am creating a file on the fly in Google Drive using PHP and Google Drive API. The api allows you to add data while you are creating it , I know I can use spreadsheet API to add data later, but I want to add data on the fly , Here is my code

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle( 'Hello world!' );
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$data = "Header1,Header2,Header2,"; // CSV
$file->setMimeType( 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' );
    $file = $service->files->insert( $file , array(
  'data' => $data,
  'convert' => true, ));
```

Here is my code, that successfully creates the file with title and description but doesn't add the headers, am I missing something ?

Comment: You probably forgot something or where are the $service defined?

Comment: @RogerWayne I just pasted the snippet, since the file is being created fine so assume that the $service is defined with no issue, I will update though.

Comment: Do you mean writing on spreadsheet cells using PHP?

Comment: @noogui yes ofcourse, how else we can add data to spreadsheet other than writing to cells.

Comment: @noogui yes, it is resoved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First setup the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php) for Sheets API. It includes the authentication and authorization processes you need.
Then checkout the guide on [Writing on Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values).

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/range?valueInputOption=valueInputOption
```

When I wrote on a spreadsheet, I used XHR requests in JS. It's up to you to do it in PHP, might be easier.
My xhr request body looked like:

```
         var params = {
           "range":"Sheet1!A1",
           "majorDimension": "ROWS",
           "values": [
           ["This is a test"]
          ],
         }
```

Just take note of your *spreadsheetId* and *sheetId*. You can find the [sheetId](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts) of the open sheet in the spreadsheet URL.